# Is JSON acceptable for storing/ accessing static data?

Tags: javascript, json, database

I'm building a nodejs app that needs access to some data. I am not sure what is the best way to store the data. If it is json or mongodb or a sql database considering the performance of the **read operation**.
The app will never update/ insert/ delete any of the data. That's why I wrote it is static. And the amount of data could be a total of at most a few hundreds small objects.

What is your opinion on that? Really considering the max performance of the read operation.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: If you are never modifying the data, then a static file you can fetch is the easy way to do it.  Reason being, is that there is no overhead needed that a database affords you.  You could create a service class which fetches the desired values and storing it in memory, then accessing as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* opinion based.

The answer is a flat file.

Reasoning:  When leveraging a database, there are defined use cases.  triggers, inserts, deletes, updates, etc.  All of this is managed by a database language of your choosing.

If you are not leveraging any key aspects of a database, then why do you need the overhead of it.

The best way to approach this situation would be to consolidate the access to a class you create called: StaticService or whatever fits your fancy.  In this class you will read in the data and store it in memory as a property.  Then have various methods in that service which will get you the data you request.

Even with a Database, you would still implement this kind of service worker, but you dont have this overhead.  You can also optimize it as you see fit, but it sounds like you may be looking to display lists, or specific values which are generally o(1) access if the json is designed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is 'static' data and that too only a few hundreds small objects, I'd recommend that you go ahead with JSON. SQL should be preferred when operations such as data manipulation, concurrent sessions etc. are involved.